# Best assembler -> C book?

Tags: c++, c, x86, assembly

I know there are good assembler books and there are good C/C++ books, but is there a book which maps the two programming languages/levels together?

Comment: Just get a good C book. The worst code I've ever come across was written by an assembler programmer who had taught himself C and tried to map it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be asking how [*compilers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers) work.  The [latest version](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321486811) of the so-called "Dragon book" by Aho and Ullman is probably still the most popular textbook on compiler construction.  I read the [original](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201000229) in the early 80s.  I liked this book and found it very useful and helpful to me in what turned into a career building compilers.

Comment: For a more down-to-earth look at compiler construction check out [LCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCC_(compiler)), the code is at http://sites.google.com/site/lccretargetablecompiler/